# Problem displaying drawing of a path in camera/viewport

Tags: camera, game-maker, viewport, path

**I have an adm object, which draws the path in the room like this (Object ADM - Draw Event):**

```
draw_set_color(c_black);

repeat(5){
    repeat(5){
        draw_path(circuito_australia,684+i,568+j,false);
        j+=1;
    }
    i+=1;
    j=0;
}

i=0;
j=0;
```

**Result:**

[image]

**I created 2 viewports, to more closely display specific cars:**

[image]

**And this problem happens, parts of the circuit in the view of these cameras are wrong/bugged:**

[image]

The reason I know (or at least I imagine) is because I'm taking a part of the room and doubling its display.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution I found is not unique.

Just on the game screen (with the code of the question itself) take a printscreen and add as a sprite in the game.

**Problem and printscreen:**

[image]

Obviously the printscreen has to be taken without the objects present in the circuit being visible. Just disable the visibility of objects.

**The code looks like this:**

```
draw_sprite(spr_circuit,0,0,0);

repeat(5){
    repeat(5){
        draw_path(circuito,x0+i,y0+j,false);
        j+=1;
    }
    i+=1;
    j=0;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**I did a test and found that after drawing the circuit image, the following part of the code becomes unnecessary (draw_path):**

```
repeat(5){
    repeat(5){
        draw_path(circuito,x0+i,y0+j,false);
        j+=1;
    }
    i+=1;
    j=0;
}
```

Just need to draw the printscreen you took (`draw_sprite(spr_circuit,0,0,0);`).

So you only need to use the function (`draw_path`) to get the printscreen out.